# pickerview does not display data from an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uipickerview

`PikerView` in my view controller is not displaying data.

It works fine when I test it with some Array literal values.

Should I be reloading data somewhere?

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet var baseCurrency: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var excahngeCurrency: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var dropDown: UIPickerView!

    var list: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()
    var titles: [String] = []
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url:URL = URL(string: "https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json?app_id=7486951aeb994599a08cd7979bef3c03")!
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler:
        {
            response in
            switch response.result
            {
            case.success:
                self.list = response.result.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                for (key, _) in self.list
                {
                    self.titles += [key]
                }

                print(self.titles)
            case.failure:
                print("error")
            }
        })
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        return self.titles[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.titles.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        exchangeCurrency.text = self.titles[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you do get data from the URL (I did not verify that and I assume you do see the data in the `print` statement you have) you need to call `reloadAllComponents` on your pickerview for it to reload the data after the data is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `success` block as:

```
case success:

    self.list = reponse.result.value as! [String: AnyObject]

    for (key, _) in self.list {
        self.titles += [key]
    }

    print(self.titles)

    if (self.titles.count > 0) {
        // reload your picker view
        self.dropDown.reloadAllComponents()
    } else {
        print("there is no data for your picker view")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Krunal. When i add it , I get the following error :  Ambiguous reference to member 'pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)'

Comment: Can you share exact error line... Did you use your own picker view instance here... dropDown. I think you just copied my code and replaced it with your own. You may not have updated picker instance. I've updated my answer. Try again if you've not updated picker instance.

Comment: @Phani.m - You can accept and upvote this answer, if it solved your problem.